# Pass the animation reference to the animbp blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

I would like to be passing the variable from the thirdpersoncharacter to the blueprint animbp, if in case you have tbm alternatives accepted, I thank you

[image: animbp]

[image: thridpersonchar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you do not pass in values directly to the Animation Blueprint, the Animation Blueprint instead reads values from a reference to the Pawn Owner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plug Get Anim Instance into the Object Wildcard and it should work. It returns the instance the skeletal mesh is using, whether that be an animation or an ABP